# Subsetting data from a dataframe and taking specific values from the subsetted values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to check if values (in example below "letters") in 1 dataframe appear in another dataframe. And if that is the case, I want a value (in example below "ranking") which is specific for that value from the first dataframe to be added to the second dataframe... What I have now Is the following:

```
Df1 <- data.frame(c("A", "C", "E"), c(1:3))
colnames(Df1) <- c("letters", "ranking")

Df2 <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
colnames(Df2) <- c("letters")

Df2$rank <- ifelse(Df2$letters %in% Df1$letters, 1, 0)
```

However... Instead of getting a '1' when the letters overlap, I want to get the specific 'ranking' number from Df1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a **merge**:

```
merge(Df2, Df1, by="letters", all.x=TRUE)
```

Also, fun fact, you can create a dataframe and name the columns at the same time (and you'll usually want to "turn off" strings as factors):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    letters = c("a", "b", "c"), 
    ranking = 1:3, 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow yeah, I guess you're right. Is it possible with merge() to get a specific value instead of NA?

Comment: No, but it's an easy fix after the merge.  Let's say you do `df <- merge(...)` so that the after-merging dataframe is named `df`.  Then do `df[is.na(df$ranking), "ranking"] <- 99` or whatever specific value you want instead of 99.

Answer (score 1):

dplyr package is best for this.

```
Df2 <- Df2 %>%
    left_join(Df1,by = "letters")
```

this will show a NA for "D" if you want to keep it.

Otherwise you can do semi_join

```
DF2 <- Df2 %>%
   semi_join(Df1, by = "letters")
```

And this will only keep the ones they have in common (intersection)